# Android Studio Emulator is not running my app

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to run my application, Android Studio loads my emulator but it says: "waiting device to come online" forever, then when I try to run my app with the emulator open, It says my emulator is already running and it doesn't launch my app. I already tried to delete the *.lock files and even tried to delete and create another emulator, without success.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should start your emulator first and then install your app. Try it...

Comment: I tried, same problem: "emulator is already running"

Comment: I've had a similar problem. I fixed it first by creating a new emulator but then restarting my computer did the trick.

Comment: I already tried to restart my computer, without any success.
I even tried to reinstall Android Studio and it didn't help.

Comment: Could you please try running the emulator from a terminal with '-verbose' option and posting its output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who helped me with my problem.
I solved the problem reinstalling Android Studio one more time and creating a new emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Genymotion which is very good emulator for Android software development. There was a huge perfermonce difference between the native emulator. Native emulator caught it up to it lately but still Genymotion is better i think

Comment: Unfortunately I can't afford Genymotion

Comment: @PedrodeAlbuquerque There is a free version.